# can't run lspci in centos 6?

Tags: centos, centos-6

trying to run lspci but it doesn't seem to be working?

```
[Ramy@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install pciutils
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: mirror.metrocast.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.constant.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pciutils.i686 0:3.1.4-11.el6 set to be updated
 Dependency: pciutils-libs = 3.1.4-11.el6 for package: pciutils-3.1.4-11.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pciutils-libs.i686 0:3.1.4-11.el6 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                Arch          Version               Repository     Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 pciutils               i686          3.1.4-11.el6          base           83 k
Updating for dependencies:
 pciutils-libs          i686          3.1.4-11.el6          base           34 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       0 Package(s)
Upgrade       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 117 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): pciutils-3.1.4-11.el6.i686.rpm                    |  83 kB     00:00     
(2/2): pciutils-libs-3.1.4-11.el6.i686.rpm               |  34 kB     00:00     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                            98 kB/s | 117 kB     00:01     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating       : pciutils-libs-3.1.4-11.el6.i686                          1/4 
  Updating       : pciutils-3.1.4-11.el6.i686                               2/4 
  Cleanup        : pciutils-3.1.4-9.el6.i686                                3/4 
  Cleanup        : pciutils-libs-3.1.4-9.el6.i686                           4/4 

Updated:
  pciutils.i686 0:3.1.4-11.el6                                                  

Dependency Updated:
  pciutils-libs.i686 0:3.1.4-11.el6                                             

 Complete!
[Ramy@localhost ~]$ lspci | grep VGA
bash: lspci: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Command not found" is quite something different than "it doesn't seem to be working".

Either lspci got installed to a place which is not in your path, or you use a shell which needs rehash to update its directory cache.

Note that you did try to run it normal user. Thus /sbin, /usr/sbin and /usr/local/sbin probably are not in your path.

Comment: ok, weird. adding sudo got it to work. pardon my ignorance, but what does that mean exactly? Super Users have a different path than regular users?

Comment: Yes. Binaries used by superusers/root are traditionally stores in /sbin (supervisor binaries). This is an artifact from the time when drives where still very slow. Other artifact from that time are /bin and /sbin (needed to bring the system up. must be on the core disk), /usr/sbin and /usr/bin (usually secondary drives. Could be network mounted).

Comment: is there a way to make any given program available to all users, since it's not strictly a privilege issue?

Comment: The easiest way to do that for a single command is to add a (soft)link to a normal directory. Use `ln -s` for that. E.g `ln -s /usr/local/sbin/lscpi /usr/local/bin' (Adjust paths as desired and document it).